# Identifying multiple columns by name in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to select a subset of columns using text matching or regular expressions?

In R it would be like this:

```
attach(iris) #Load the 'Stairway to Heaven' of R's built-in data sets
iris[grep(names(iris),pattern="Length")] #Prints only columns containing the word "Length"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) method for this (use `axis=1` to filter on the column names). This function has different possibilities:

- Equivalent to `if 'Length' in col`:

  ```
  df.filter(like='Length', axis=1)
  ```
- Using a regex (however, it is using `re.search` and not `re.match`, so you have possibly to adjust the regex):

  ```
  df.filter(regex=r'\.Length$', axis=1)
  ```

Comment: Very good info @joris. But I also need to get the column names which contains some other characters also along with the column name. For example "Length_1", "Length_2", "Width_1", "Width_2", etc.. are my column names. My filter function is like df.filter(like=col+'_', axis=1) where col will have values like "Length", "Width", etc... which is not fetching values . Any idea what should I correct ?

Comment: You should be able to do that with a regular expression, eg `regex=r"Length|Width"`

Answer (score 0):

Using Python's `in` statement, it would work like this:

```
#Assuming iris is already loaded as a df called 'iris' and has a proper header
iris = iris[[col for col in iris.columns if 'Length' in col]]
print iris.head()
```

Or, using regular expressions,

```
import re
iris = iris[[col for col in iris.columns if re.match(r'\.Length$',col)]]
print iris.head()
```

The first will run faster but the second will be more accurate.